# Magento PDF invoice totals

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice

I have Magento web shop with prices on totals displaying both with included and excluded tax. On my cart and sales emails, the order of the totals is normal, like: 
Product price Incl tax 
Product price Excl tax 
Shipping price Incl tax 
Shipping price Ecl tax 
Tax for shipping 
Tax for product

Only on my PDF invoices, I have things unsorted, like. 
Product price Incl tax 
Product price Excl tax 
Tax for shipping 
Tax for product 
Shipping price Incl tax 
Shipping price Ecl tax

Is there a way to change order of the totals in PDF invoices and where?

Answer (score 2):

You can find totals sort order here `app/code/core/mage/sales/etc/config.xml` under the node `pdf`.You need to override the config.xml.The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5993891/1957705) descibes how to do it.